# Creating new rows using arrayformula if a cell contains info

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a list of products (bundles of items, eg a number of different books) on single rows in a spreadsheet.

EG:

| product | book 1 | book 2 | book 3 | book 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | ISBN 1 | ISBN 2 | ISBN 3 |  |
| Product B | ISBN 11 | ISBN 12 | ISBN 13 | ISBN 14 |

I'd like to split each row into separate rows like so:

| product | include |
| --- | --- |
| Product A | ISBN 1 |
| Product A | ISBN 2 |
| Product A | ISBN 3 |
| Product B | ISBN 11 |
| Product B | ISBN 12 |
| Product B | ISBN 13 |
| Product B | ISBN 14 |

The products may have different numbers of books included, and I am pulling data from a spreadsheet with other columns (ie the info needed is not in consecutive columns).

Looking for an arrayformula (I think) that can achieve this, any pointers?

UPDATE:

Managed a flat version of this using the following - BUT how can this be used to process lots of rows with `arrayformula`?

```
=TRANSPOSE({
'products'!C1,'products'!C1,'products'!C1,'products'!C1,'products'!C1,'products'!C1,'products'!C1; 
'products'!D1,'products'!D1,'products'!D1,'products'!D1,'products'!D1,'products'!D1, 'products'!D1; 
'products'!F1,'products'!I1,'products'!L1,'products'!O1,'products'!R1,'products'!U1,'products'!X1; 
'products'!G1,'products'!J1,'products'!M1,'products'!P1,'products'!S1,'products'!V1,'products'!Y1
})
```

which looks like:

| bundle_product_id | bundle_variant_id | child_product_id | child_variant_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| product_1 | variant_id | ISBN 1 PRODUCT ID | ISBN 1 VARIANT ID |
| product_1 | variant_id | ISBN 2 PRODUCT ID | ISBN 2 VARIANT ID |
| product_1 | variant_id | ISBN 3 PRODUCT ID | ISBN 3 VARIANT ID |
| product_1 | variant_id | ISBN 4 PRODUCT ID | ISBN 4 VARIANT ID |
| product_1 | variant_id | ISBN 5 PRODUCT ID | ISBN 5 VARIANT ID |
| product_1 | variant_id | ISBN 6 PRODUCT ID | ISBN 6 VARIANT ID |
| product_1 | variant_id | ISBN 7 PRODUCT ID | ISBN 7 VARIANT ID |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the formula that I wrote, based on your first question:

```
=index(split(flatten("product|include",A2&"|"& Filter(B2:2,B2:2<>""),A3&"|"& Filter(B3:3,B3:3<>"")),"|"))
```

Essentially Flatten() appends the elements of a row, Filter
() checks that the cells are not empty, Split() creates two columns of data.
I think that it solves your problem.

**update**: filter() now verifies that the cells examined contain the codes of the books

See the [test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MECEZ78FmTkImSXyTdRLoR1ZKZxgfKubLa8EaU1bj5U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: That's very helpful @Daniele, thanks.

How would you combine this with arrayformula to go through dozens of rows?

Comment: That formula expands at this moment by itself, based on each new column of books, credit to index (). Automatic expansion ALSO based on the number of lines of the various products is currently not provided

Comment: Although I don't like it very much (I couldn't simplify it), the second formula should answer your new request for extension to all lines

Comment: Aha very interesting! Having a look now! Thanks @Daniele

Comment: I've been looking at this and scratching my head trying to extend it. I'm trying to add another column to this, with a product VARIANT (every ISBN also has a VARIANT)... I've started to set this up on your demo page, but can't see how to create the third column? Any hints greatly appreciated @Daniele !! 8•)

Comment: What should be the end result with the introduction of the variants?

Comment: Hi Daniele - corresponding variant - I changed columns on ORIGIN to illustrate 

Comment: See yellow columns in RESULT sheet, I think that are OK

Comment: Bravo @Daniele - thanks a million for your help! I've got it working!